# Git unknown switch 'C'

Tags: git, git-add

I have a weird case - My git was working fine till an hour ago or so but now when I try to run

```
git add * --all
```

I get an error saying **error: unknown switch `C'**.

Below is the output I got. I just pulled from the repo which had some changes and after that I started getting this error. Tried poking around a bit and found that the error comes because of the `*` sign. If I remove that, it works....

```
$ git add * --all
error: unknown switch `C'

usage: git add [options] [--] <pathspec>...

-n, --dry-run         dry run
-v, --verbose         be verbose

-i, --interactive     interactive picking
-p, --patch           select hunks interactively
-e, --edit            edit current diff and apply
-f, --force           allow adding otherwise ignored files
-u, --update          update tracked files
-N, --intent-to-add   record only the fact that the path will be added later

-A, --all             add changes from all tracked and untracked files
--ignore-removal      ignore paths removed in the working tree (same as --no-all)
--refresh             don't add, only refresh the index
--ignore-errors       just skip files which cannot be added because of errors
--ignore-missing      check if - even missing - files are ignored in dry run
```

Comment: You have a file named `-C`, so `add *` turns into `add -C file1 file2...`.

Comment: Thank @torek, found the file and deleted it. If any one else is looking for something similar, delete the file using rm -- -c [-- prevents the command from parsing the parameters]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not have options (like `--all`) like after parameters (like filenames). So try switching them around:

```
git add --all *
```

Additionally, if a filename begins with a minus it will be mis-interpreted as an option (a file `-Clown` looks like options `-C -l -o -w -n` to programs on the commandline). To mitigate this you can stop option parsing using `--`:

```
git add --all -- *
```

Comment: While you are correct, as Mureinik noted the combination of `--all` and `*` doesn't make sense. Maybe you want to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

switches should come before the file list - I'm guessing you have a file named `C` which the `*` is expanded to by the shell. Note, however, that with `--all` you do not need to provide a file list:

```
git add --all
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be running in a Powershell console. (that was my case)

(If you want to keep the output in the same console window you can just start an "ordinary" command in your console through `cmd`. (it will have its own history though) You then leave it by `exit`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, it's probably because you're using Visual Studio's command prompt, or some other special Windows command utility. Use the basic Command Prompt, or use Git Bash (which is what I did). The command I was trying was:

```
git merge --squash HEAD@{1}
```

After trying it in a git-bash window, it worked.

Comment: your answer has nothing to do with the problem. please consider removing it and ask yourself have I provided a solution that applies directly to the question asked and would resolve it?  The OP's question had an issue in his command that would be wrong on any console. Your answer is ostensibly to a different question entirely.

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with the problem? Really? Because this is the exact error message that I got, and the answer that I provided fixed the issue for me - switching to a different console window. Obviously I did not have the same command, but the same error, with a different solution.

Comment: Yes.  Your answer has nothing to do with git add. You may have had the same error message but the cause was entirely different. The question title isn't the only piece that matters.  His question matters and your answer does not solve his problem his command itself is bad. It's great that you're trying to help. Please don't take this the wrong way.  It just isn't answering this question. When you are in the wrong place "git anything" will fail right?

Comment: I can't tell you how many problems I have solved because I scrolled down to find other answers that solved my problem.

This is an error I got. I got it for a different reason, but I got the same error. Sure, this answer does not solve this person's problem, but if Stackoverflow was meant to only solve this person's problem, it would be a private customer service, not a public forum.

I'd rather be useful than a pedant.

Comment: your anecdotal evidence is meaningless here. You are answering a different problem entirely. open a different question that explains YOUR situation so that someone is likely to find it and I would upvote your answer. Here it is nonsense.  It not the same error.  Stackoverflow answers are meant to solve the question being asked. A good question is applicable to many people and just that user.